# Google Maps iOS SDK Route Preview/Snapshot

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, gmsmapview

I have a task to build a preview of a route in `UITableViewCell`.
Inserting `GMSMapView` in each cell doesn't sound good to me because I'm worried about performance, so the question is there any way how to get a route snapshot? Thanks!

[image]